# PHP change href on specific pages

Tags: javascript, php, href

I am new to PHP. I am trying to replace the hash tags in the headers of all the pages that aren't part of the index page. I am using this code

```
$content = file_get_contents('includes/header.php');

if ( strpos( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 'index.php' ) === false ){

  preg_replace( 'href="#', 'href="index\.php#', $content );

}
```

However I am getting "Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in " and I don't know how to escape the characters more than using backslash.

Should I just run some javascript instead?

Thanks

Comment: @HeHui The error is gone but no result. perhaps links from the $contents aren't been returned or updated correctly. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace` expects parameter 1 to be a pattern and is missing the delimiters. So you need to do something like:

```
preg_replace('/href="#/', 'href="index\.php#', $content);
```

http://www.php.net/preg_replace

Answer (score -1):

The 'hash' of the url cannot be accessed by the server, only by the client.

The only way to manipulate this part of the URL is by using a client side scripting language, e.g. JavaScript.

Comment: Ok well is javascript the only alternative? I am using that solution now, just seems like there should be some way in PHP to do this...

Comment: He's replacing the `href` value of `a` tags, not the hash in the current URI, so it's possible.